# Shell script to print the entire line from some given lines if true

Tags: shell

We need to write a script taking the input file which contains number of lines,
where in one line it has 5 delimeters ( 1|2|3|4|5).

Assume file has 3 lines like

20|30|10|40

40|50|60|70

5|3|2|1

We need to read the file line by line and check if the second delimeter value is greater than third value (i.e., 30>10). If it is true, print the whole line and as well as print all the lines where 2nd value > 3rd value.

Need anyone's help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: @AjayKumar : Wouldn't this be easier in `awk` then in Posix shell?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. Read the file into a loop and for each line, split it into an array and print it if `arr[1] > arr[2]`:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do

  # split line on spaces and pipes
  IFS='| ' read -r -a arr <<< "$line"

  # echo line if second elem > third elem
  if [[ ${arr[1]} -gt ${arr[2]} ]]; then
    echo $line
  fi
done < text
```

Output:

```
a | 30 | 20 | 40 | 50
c | 20 | 10 | 30 | 40
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually we need to write a script taking the input file which contains number of lines where in one line it has 5 delimeters ( 1|2|3|4|5). We need to read it line by line and check if the second value is greater than third value (2>3). If it is true, print the whole line and as well as print all the lines where 2>3